# I am getting redirected in cs servers while playing

Tags: steam, counter-strike

I am playing cs1 CS 1.6 reloaded and I am getting redirected to another server even if I haven't pressed anything during a gameplay (not at start of the game). Its like, even when I am playing offline with bots sometimes, I get redirected onto any random server.

I removed all the servers from my favourites and even reinstalled CS Reloaded but the problem continues and I can't play at a single game.

Something tells me that you I had to bind some keys, but I don't know how to bind also so how and why this is happening!!!

Comment: this happened to me once idk but maybe bcoz of few pluggins that have been downloaded from a server which creates this typos problem.a fresh install will always solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, go into your controls and click the `Use defaults` button as shown below.
[image]